How do I decide the specifications for a compute cluster that I need for a fine-tuning task in Azure ML?
I was using the Standard_NC48ads_A100_v4 Compute cluster with 2 nodes to fine-tune a Phi-3-mini-128k-instruct model. The data used for the same was around 25 MB. I set the training batch size to 10. The fine-tuning job failed and returned an error that there was not enough memory on the GPU.
NOTE : The specs for the above are - 24 cores, 220GB RAM, 64GB storage
I want to increase the batch size during fine-tuning. How do I get an estimate of how much RAM and storage I will need for the same given that I know the model is around 7.6 GB and I know the data size? Could this be resolved just by increasing the number of nodes?
I could only get this to work by removing max_padding and setting the training batch size to 1. I had initially applied lora with rank 16 and enabled deep speed as well.

I don't think you can estimate this sort of thing. Machine learning models and algorithms are buried so deep in a black box that you cannot apply a mathematical equation to get an estimate. My best advice is to experiment. Identify the variables that you think could affect the amount of RAM and then follow the Scientific Method. Form your hypothesis, change one variable, run a test, record the results.
I think the most significant metric to record is, of course, RAM usage. Start a spreadsheet that tracks the variables you are tweaking, the values of the variables (like batch size, CPU cores, etc), and the resulting RAM usage. After enough experiments create a graph if the RAM usage. You might notice a trend. With enough permutations of your experiment, you might even derive a statistical formula to match your experiment results, and then based on this math formula, plug in the numbers for your current training set. See where the numbers take you.
You might not get a precise measure, but this might be good enough for a rough estimate. In the very least it might inform you whether you need "more nodes" or "a whole server farm." This might suffice to go back to management and either ask for more resources and money, or they might axe this whole idea because it isn't worth the time, money, and resources.
